# Robot framework: Retrieving keys that contain dashes from a dict

Tags: json, dictionary, robotframework

I am new to Robot Framework and am trying to validate the contents of some JSON that is returned from a web service.  The problem is that some attributes of the json objects have dashes in them and Robot doesn't seem to like this.  I have something like the following

```
&{deployment} =  list deployment  ${deployment_name}
&{changeSets} =  Set Variable  ${deployment.ChangeSets}
&{myChangeSet} =  Set Variable  ${changeSets.my-change-set}

Should Be True  ${myChangeSet.UseLocal} 
Should Be Equal As Strings  ${myChangeSet.Version}  ${update_version}
```

But Robot fails on the 3rd line with the following error:

```
Resolving variable '${changeSets.my-change-set}' failed: AttributeError: my
```

I tried to escape the dashes but that still doesn't seem to work:

```
Resolving variable '${changeSets.my\-change\-set}' failed: SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character (<string>, line 1)
```

I can't seem to find any information in the Robot docs with other ways to retrieve dict keys outside of the dot-notation.   Any suggestions?

Comment: just a guess, but have you tried `${changeSets['my-change-set']}`?

Comment: @ErikAllik  hey! that worked.  I guess you can use python notation inside of the curly brackets... don't know why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of dot notation is just a convenience. You can still access them the normal way (documented in the [dictionary variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#dictionary-variables) section of the user guide as `&{NAME}[key]`):

```
&{changeSets}[my-change-set]
```

Or, with [extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax), which treats everything inside {} as a python expression:

```
${changeSets['my-change-set']}
```

Here is a working example illustrating these two methods:

```
*** Variables ***
&{changeSets}    my-change-set=foo

*** Test Cases ***
Test 1
    should be equal    ${changeSets['my-change-set']}    foo

Test 2
    should be equal    &{changeSets}[my-change-set]    foo
```